# Create a vector with the value 0 instead of NULL when counting the numbers of TRUE

Tags: r, vector, binary, recode

I'd like to count the numbers of `TRUE` of a variable for each category of another variable. Or more precisely the average number of `TRUE` for each category. Afterward, I'd like to create a vector.

The code I use works fine, when the variable, like `Var2` contains, both `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. However when like `Var3` the variable only contains `FALSE`, my code creates a vector with the value of NULL. However I would like it to create a vector with the value of 0 for each category.

Any ideas?

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C"),
  Var2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  Var3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
)
#creating some data


count1 = as.vector(tapply(df$Var1, df$Var2, table)$'TRUE')/nrow(df)
#this works fine

count2 = as.vector(tapply(df$Var1, df$Var3, table)$'TRUE')/nrow(df)
#this not. It creates only a NULL-vector
```

`count1` works as inteded, but `count2` is a NULL-vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `aggregate(x = cbind(count1 = df$Var2, count2 = df$Var3), by = list(df$Var1), FUN = \(x) sum(x) / nrow(df))`  `sum()` is neat in combination with boolean variables as it counts `TRUE` values. Your results are shares not counts to be precise.

Comment: Worked! I used the following code to create a vector afterward:
`y<-as.vector(aggregate(x = (shareVar3 = df$Var3), by = list(df$Var1), FUN = \(x) sum(x) / nrow(df)))$x`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to dynamically build it in base R without having to explicitly name the variables.

```
i1 <- as.formula(paste("cbind(", 
                       paste(setdiff(names(df), "Var1"), collapse = ", "),
                       ") ~ Var1"))
res <- aggregate(i1, df,  \(i) sum(i) / nrow(df))

res
# Var1      Var2 Var3
#1    A 0.5000000    0
#2    B 0.0000000    0
#3    C 0.1666667    0
```